# Reserve with Google RwG payment implementation

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem implementing payments in Reserve with Google (RwG).
I have a full working booking server, without any problem the past 6 years and bookings are working just fine. I have try to implement payments but I don't have succeded.

Sample from Merchants Feed

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "processing_instruction": "PROCESS_AS_COMPLETE",
        "shard_number": 0,
        "total_shards": 1,
        "generation_timestamp": 1662023600
    },
    "merchant": [
        {
            "category": "restaurant",
            "geo": {
                "latitude": "87.33154",
                "longitude": "99.14578",
                "address": {
                    "street_address": "Somewhere in the world",
                    "postal_code": "648775",
                    "locality": "Corfu",
                    "country": "Greece"
                }
            },
            "merchant_id": "91795554321547",
            "name": "La tratoria el Dingo",
            "tax_rate": {
                "micro_percent": 24000000
            },
            "telephone": "+1537784315823",
            "terms": {
                "text": "Just enjoy our dishes"
            },
            "tokenization_config": {
                "tokenization_parameter": {
                    "gateway": "vivawallet",
                    "gatewayMerchantId": "3efa44f3-232f44fea-984617abaaaaa2cca-0823deff9340bb"
                },
                "billing_information_format": "MIN",
                "merchant_of_record_name": "LA TRATA LTD",
                "payment_country_code": "GR"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample from Services Feed

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "processing_instruction": "PROCESS_AS_COMPLETE",
        "shard_number": 0,
        "total_shards": 1,
        "generation_timestamp": 1662023600
    },
    "service": [
        {
            "localized_service_name": {
                "value": "Reservation",
                "localized_value": [
                    {
                        "locale": "en",
                        "value": "Reservation"
                    },
                    {
                        "locale": "el",
                        "value": "Κράτηση"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "merchant_id": "91795554321547",
            "prepayment_type": "PREPAYMENT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
            "service_id": "reservation",
            "type": "SERVICE_TYPE_DINING_RESERVATION"
        }
    ]
}
```

Sample from Availability Feed:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "processing_instruction": "PROCESS_AS_COMPLETE",
        "shard_number": 0,
        "total_shards": 1,
        "generation_timestamp": 1662023601
    },
    "service_availability": [
        {
            "availability": [
                {
                    "duration_sec": 7200,
                    "merchant_id": "91795554321547",
                    "resources": {
                        "party_size": 2
                    },
                    "scheduling_rule_overrides": {
                        "last_bookable_sec": 1662015600,
                        "first_bookable_sec": 1660208400,
                        "last_online_cancellable_sec": 1662015600
                    },
                    "service_id": "reservation",
                    "spots_open": 2,
                    "spots_total": 2,
                    "start_sec": 1662022800
                },
                {
                    "deposit": {
                        "deposit": {
                            "price_micros": 12000000,
                            "currency_code": "EUR"
                        },
                        "min_advance_cancellation_sec": 7200,
                        "deposit_type": "PER_PERSON"
                    },
                    "duration_sec": 7200,
                    "merchant_id": "91795554321547",
                    "require_credit_card": "REQUIRE_CREDIT_CARD_ALWAYS",
                    "resources": {
                        "party_size": 3
                    },
                    "scheduling_rule_overrides": {
                        "last_bookable_sec": 1664571599,
                        "first_bookable_sec": 1662840000,
                        "last_online_cancellable_sec": 1664571599
                    },
                    "service_id": "reservation",
                    "spots_open": 0,
                    "spots_total": 2,
                    "start_sec": 1664654400
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When my clients are try to book without payment everything is ok.
When I put a price in order to proceed to payment I get a generic error from google "There was a problem with your booking".

I have tried with stripe and vivawallet. The problem is the same.
I contact vivawallet, and they did a search on their system, and they couldn't find any initial request from google. So that means that google doesn't even reach on step 2 in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/verticals/dining/guides/payments/enabling-payments#deposits-and-no-show-fees)

I have successful payments on other platforms with stripe and vivawallet, and I don't think that is a payment provider problem.
I think that my feeds have problem but I can't find it...

Thanks

Documentation
[Examples](https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/verticals/dining/samples/end-to-end-feed-samples/vertical-specific-feeds/dining_wpay#merchants)
[Enabling Payments](https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/verticals/dining/guides/payments/enabling-payments#deposits-and-no-show-fees)
[Feed Overview](https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/verticals/dining/reference/feed-specifications/feed-overview)

Comment: What does this have to do with [google-maps]?

Comment: Well I think that is related since the booking starts by navigating in google maps. I couldn't find anything related and my reputation doesn't allow creating new tag.